# MySQL Node.js Syntax Error (DRIVING ME CRAZY)

Tags: mysql, node.js, syntax, syntax-error

I'm getting an error that says:

```
C:\Users\Minh Lu\Desktop\MusicMediaWebApp\database\dbService.js:34
[0]             con.query(sql, typeCast: function(field, next) {
[0]                            ^^^^^^^^
[0]
[0] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

From this:

```
/* Retrieves a User model by ID */
    getUserByID: function(ID, callback) {
        this.tryConnect().getConnection(function(err, con) {
            var sql = queries.getUserByID;
            con.query(sql, typeCast: function(field, next) {

                // We only want to cast bit fields that have a single-bit in them. If the field
                // has more than one bit, then we cannot assume it is supposed to be a Boolean.
                if ( ( field.type === "BIT" ) && ( field.length === 1 ) ) {

                    var bytes = field.buffer();

                    // A Buffer in Node represents a collection of 8-bit unsigned integers.
                    // Therefore, our single "bit field" comes back as the bits '0000 0001',
                    // which is equivalent to the number 1.
                    return( bytes[ 0 ] === 1 );

                }
                return next();

            }, ID, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                // Call the callback function in the caller of this method so we can do something with this "result"
                return callback(result); // [] if not found
            });
        });
    },
```

And I'm so confused as to what syntax error this is? This is the same method as in the documentation: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#type-casting

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at the documentation.

```
connection.query({
  sql: '...',
  typeCast: function (field, next) {
    if (field.type == 'TINY' && field.length == 1) {
      return (field.string() == '1'); // 1 = true, 0 = false
    }
    return next();
  }
});
```

`connection.query(...)` is accepting an object as the parameter.

Comment: Yeah I realized that. Thanks!